# determine actual contents of a byte array

Tags: java

Does java have a function that will in essence "dump" the contents of a byte array? 
I'm trying to determine the true contents of a byte array when I convert the 8 byte array to  a string. I get the following:

```
2011.05.28 17:13:25 ConversationID from cm_init is [B@46e446e4
```

where [B@46e446e4 is the contents of the string field.

Generated from the byte array, I count a "string" of 11 characters. When there should only be 8.

I have defined:

```
static byte[] conversation_ID = new byte[8];
static String convrsID;
```

when I want to "look" at the conversation_ID value --> `convrsID = conversation_ID.toString();` both the `convrsID` and the `conversation_ID` show a length of 8 via the respective length functions.

Thanks

Guy

Answer (score 7):

Use `Arrays.toString(byte[])`.

Answer (score 1):

If the contents of the bytes is binary use Arrays.toString(byte[]) however if the contents is ASCII text you can use `new String(bytes, 0)`

Answer (score 0):

Try simply to use

```
static String convrsID= new String (conversation_ID );
```