# get byte array from database

Tags: java, angularjs, mongodb

I would like to get a byte array (java) from the database (mongo) and manipulate it, send it to the DOM as the original image, etc.

```
BasicDBObject condition = new BasicDBObject("_id", new ObjectId(_id));
    DBObject dataset = DataAccess.GetInstanceClass().Getdatasets().findOne(condition);
    byte[] image = (byte[]) dataset.get("image").toString().getBytes();

    String s = new String(image);
    System.out.println("provider: " + s);
```

This only returns 
INFO: provider: [B@3b249009

Comment: "[B@3b249009" is the result of calling `toString` on a `byte[]` object.

Comment: Initially, I would like to dump it in the glassfish console just to give me confidence that it's being returned, then I would like to return it to the view as an image. It seems like Java would provide a way to convert if I want to.

Comment: That's what a debugger (or unit test) is for, not modifying source code to emit debugging junk :) In any case, you'll want to start looking at the result of `dataset.get("image")` and not the result of all the other unnecessary transformations. The operation `actualValue.toString().getBytes()` effectively obliterates whatever useful [typed] value it had - as per above, `byteArrayObject.toString()` will return "[B@deadbeef" which is *not* what you want.

Comment: Okay. Yes, of course! Type casting back and forth is ludricrous and and expresses a specific moment and level of frustration in the process. So, per your suggestion, I went back to what I had started with: ie; dataset.get() which returns a similar object [B@438d3c21 Just not sure what to do with it. I have tried numerous solutions from StackOverflow, all to no avail.

Comment: Maybe a string ("[B@438d3c21") was *stored*? If so then I suspect it was stored after `byte[]` was (accdidentally) stringified as per above.

Answer (score 0):

Doing:

```
System.out.println("provider: " + image);
```

or:

```
System.out.println("provider: " + new String(image));
```

both result in printing the default `toString()` of an array, which is the pointer to the array (in your case, the rather ugly `[B@3b249009`)

If you want to look at a more useful String representation of the byte array, you can find the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6165413/653519):

```
System.out.println("byte array as pretty string: " + Arrays.toString(image));
```

Also, as you note, you don't need to (in fact, shouldn't) do

```
dataset.get("image").toString().getBytes();
```

you're putting your data through all sorts of mangling.

I've written a short test to demonstrate how to get the byte array out of MongoDB, and the differences in writing it as the default String vs using the `Arrays.toString()` method:

```
@Test
public void shouldBeAbleToGetANiceStringRepresentationOfAByteArray() {
    // given
    ObjectId id = new ObjectId();
    byte[] bytes = {1,2,3,4};
    collection.insert(new BasicDBObject("_id", id).append("image", bytes));

    // when 
    BasicDBObject condition = new BasicDBObject("_id", id);
    DBObject dataset = collection.findOne(condition);
    byte[] image = (byte[]) dataset.get("image");

    // then
    // this instanceof is actually pointless, since casting it to a byte array above means it must be a byte array, but the point is to demonstrate it's not a String
    assertTrue(image instanceof byte[]);

    assertThat(image.toString(), startsWith("[B@"));
    assertThat(image.toString().length(), is(11));
    System.out.println("byte array toString(): " + image);

    assertThat(Arrays.toString(image), is("[1, 2, 3, 4]"));
    System.out.println("byte array as pretty string: " + Arrays.toString(image));
}
```